# Error : Not Implemented Code 0

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I keep getting this error in IE6 and 7 version s. 
The script is :

```
window.onload = checkBrowserVersion("Explorer","7");
```

That function is defined previously and I get this as not implemented

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Or...wait, I guess there's an implied question there. `checkBrowserVersion()` is not, to my knowledge, a built-in function (and I get zero useful results when googling it), so could it be that it is in a library you are using? Does it work in other versions of IE? Or other browsers?

Comment: Add code of `checkBrowserVersion()` into the question. And write a description of error in IE6-7. IE8-9, other browsers do not throw an error?

Comment: its not lib function its defined (i have stated this in Q prev)

Comment: @Andrew Description is already there in Q title, its confusing but this is what IE throws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing the function not assigning it as a handler to the onload event of window. Remove the parentheses or wrap the function call within another function.